# How to place the image outside of the div with transparent background?

Tags: css

[image]

The white part is a container div centered horizontally on the website. The stripes are the background image of the body element. I have the rest of the dumbbell as a picture and I want to place it outside of the container so that there's a complete picture.

Usually it would be positioning the image absolutely in the container div and moving it a bit to the right.

But my problem is that the background of the whole image is white. So the result is:

[image]

Is there a way to solve this?

```
<body>
   <div id="container">
      <div id="pimg"><img src="../images/image_part.png"></div>
   </div>
</body>

html {
    background-image: url('../images/stripes.png');
}

#container {
    position: relative;
    background-color: white;
    background-image: url('../images/image.png'); // first picture
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top right;
    width: 800px;
    height: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#pimg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -100px; // second image
}
```

Comment: Give your code or sample so that we can able to suggest or give solution to your problem

Comment: Edited, that's the whole code.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the following css to hide the part of the image that goes outsite the div#container

```
#container
{
overflow:hidden;
}
```

The above approach will crop the image, and if you don't want to do that you could set this so that the image has maximum width the one of it's container

```
#pimg 
{ width:800px; }
#pimg img 
{ max-width:100%; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that your PNG has a white background instead a transparent background like you want so:

- Edit "image.png" in an image editor software like Adobe Photoshop or GIMP
- Open it in the image editor
- Erease the background (because you have a PNG, yes, but it has a white background)
- Save the image in PNG or GIF format, because JPEG doesn't support transparent backgrounds
- Tip: Photoshop have an option to save a picture for the web, `Control(Command in Mac) + Shift + alt + S`, this option can help you to optimize the image adjusting its params

Here's a Photoshop tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PLA2FaOXkkg